# C++/CLI include problems

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, include, c++-cli

doing some C++/CLI coding again, and running into issues. Working in VS2008 if it matters at all.

Here's a mock up of what I am trying to do. In reality ClassA is the GUI and ClassB is the backend that the gui needs to interact with. I am trying to give them access to eachother by passing them to eachother, but I cannot properly get them in scope to create a reference to the other one.

http://pastie.org/private/tnyxazwtyzv3luddz7seq

If you have any input I would greatly appreciate it. I have spent much of today looking online and this solution I currently have has gotten me quite close but I am still getting compile errors. Here's what I am now getting:

```
Error   1   error C2653: 'NameSpaceB' : is not a class or namespace name    c:\users\andy\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\myhello\myhello\A.h 12  myhello
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^'  c:\users\andy\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\myhello\myhello\A.h 12  myhello
Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\andy\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\myhello\myhello\A.h 12  myhello
Error   4   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\andy\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\myhello\myhello\A.h 12  myhello
Error   5   error C2653: 'NameSpaceA' : is not a class or namespace name    c:\users\andy\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\myhello\myhello\B.h 12  myhello
Error   6   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^'  c:\users\andy\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\myhello\myhello\B.h 12  myhello
Error   7   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\andy\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\myhello\myhello\B.h 12  myhello
Error   8   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\andy\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\myhello\myhello\B.h 12  myhello
```

This is the same error I am getting in my actual project, so I know it's something funky with my configuration.

Comment: Ugh, circular header file dependency.

Comment: Yep, I had gotten that far, but I followed a few examples and I thought this was pretty good! The CPP's only depend on their specific headers, and then the headers cross over to the other class, seemingly eliminating the problem. Much of this was generated based on the following tutorial I read: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/organizing-code-files-in-c-and-c-r1798

Comment: I don't know what `public ref` means, is it particular to your compiler? Also, the `^` in the declaration of the `b` member seems wrong, and the compiler is complaining about it. Ah, C++/CLI. Okay.

Comment: Yes, this is specific to the CLI/CLR version of C++ that windows uses. Kind of a pain at first, but fairly similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/*B.h File Contents*/
#ifndef CLASSB_H
#define CLASSB_H
#include "A.h"
```

Remove the `#include "A.h"` part and you're golden. Since class B doesn't use A (at least in the definition), there's no need for the include.

Comment: My mistake on the pastebin. In the current example (and my project) "Class A" only references an instance of "Class B" but in reality, they will both have to reference eachother. I will post a new pastebin with this explicitly shown.

Comment: @fooOnYou replace the includes with forward declarations.

Comment: I attempted to go down this route earlier today and got a little lost trying to figure out exactly where to put the statements. I tried just now putting it where the #include was, inside the namespace(but not class) and lastly inside the class definition.

Specifically I put the in the text "class NameSpaceB::ClassB;" into file "A.h" in the specified locations. 

Thanks,

Comment: @fooOnYou inside the namespace, outside the class.

Comment: Doing that seems to get me much closer, but now I think I am missing some include, or something, as they do not see the other namespace. Here are the new errors: http://pastie.org/private/enwpvpoecuuihavr6kuwmg

Comment: ahh I wasn't bringing the name space over properly, thank you for the example. I have resolved my previous problem, onto a new one (error C3699: '^' : cannot use this indirection on type 'NameSpaceA::ClassA') I will look into this and hope I can resolve it for myself.

Thank you very much,

Comment: @fooOnYou I actually don't know how forward declarations work on ref classes. It could be as simple as adding ref to the forward declaration.

Comment: Ha, you win the day. That's all it took.